# How to change the url of a new html page in opencart?

Tags: php, url, opencart2.x

I created a new `Php` page in root of **opencart 2.0.3.1**, for example **test.php**.

The address now is: `my_domain.com/test.php`, however i want it to become: `my_domain.com/test`.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the folowing:

What you have now:

```
Root
    index.php
    test.php
```

What you can do is:

```
Root
    index.php
    test
        index.php
```

A website will always look for the index file.

If you create a new folder (in this case "**test**") and place a index in there, you're page address will look like: `my_domain.com/test`

Also, if you want a link from index.php to test. you can just simply do:

```
<a href="test/">Link</a>
```